# Pusher WebSocketError -> code:4200 - message:Please reconnect immediately

Tags: php, angularjs, pusher

we are using `Pusher` as our notification system and it is causing problem sometimes.

The issue is sometimes the connection closes automatically and the following error is printed on the console (actually this is an older error I used to get on console until some weeks ago):

> Pusher : Error :
>   {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":1006}}}

And recently I see this one:

> Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":4200,"message":"Please reconnect immediately"}}}

Here is the client (JS) code:

```
   function initPusher(user) {
      if (pusher) {
          return;
       } else {
            Pusher.logToConsole = false;
            pusher = new Pusher('pusher key', {
                cluster: 'eu',
                encrypted: true
            });

            try {
                var channel = pusher.subscribe(user.user_channel);
                channel.bind('app_event', function(data) {
                    if (data['event_type'] === 'reply-message') {
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('REPLY_RECEIVED', data);
                    } else if (data['event_type'] === 'new-message') {
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('MESSAGE_RECEIVED', data);
                    }
                });
            } catch(err) {
                $state.go('logout');
            }
        }
    }
```

This function is called on login and every page refresh.

Although I guess this is a client side issue I add the relevant PHP code where the API is instantiated in index.php:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/pusher/pusher-php-server/lib/Pusher.php';

$options = array(
    'cluster' => 'eu',
    'encrypted' => true
);

$pusher = new Pusher(
    'pusher key',
    'secret',
    'app id,
    $options
);
```

**Further Details**

- Backend framework in use is `Silex` and the frontend one `AngularJS`.
- We are using the EU cluster of Pusher and it works fine while the connection is still open.
- I have already seen [this](https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/204202193-What-is-meant-by-Error-1006-) link but couldn't find an answer to my problem there.

Comment: Have you seen [this link](https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/204202193-What-is-meant-by-Error-1006-)? Maybe you're requests are going through a proxy? Have you tried connecting to Pusher from another network?

Comment: @WillSewell Hi Will, thanks for your reply! Yeah, actually it's in the last line of my question :-) - unfortunately it doesn't provide any solution. However I've tried a solution yesterday and I think it has fixed the issue. I'll add it here in a few days after making sure it actually worked.

Comment: @Mr.Robot So what was the solution ? :)